# cant get capybara-webkit to work

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webkit, rspec2, capybara

I am using capybara to do integration testing on my rails 3 app.

When i add :js => true to a scenario my tests work with selenium but when i change to use the webkit driver for js i get errors for each like this :

Capybara::Driver::Webkit::WebkitInvalidResponseError:
Unable to load URL: http://www.example.dev:7171/user_sessions

My add is a multi domain app so in my spec_helper i set port :
Capybara.server_port = 7171

And in a background block i set the app_host like this :
Capybara.app_host = "http://#{subdomain}.example.dev:7171"

If i then add this to my spec_helper rspec.configure block i then get the errors above :

```
config.before(:each) do
   DatabaseCleaner.start
   Capybara.run_server = false
   Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
   Capybara.default_selector = :css
   Capybara.server_port = 7171 
end
```

Can anyone help with this? I am also using spork for auto testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open issue for an issue that seems exactly like this on github => https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/87

They have some workaround suggestions in there, see if that doesn't help you out. Good luck!

Comment: yes tried that but no luck thanks anyway !   any other suggestions?

Comment: sadly no :( I've upvoted your question and will keep an eye on it incase I come across something else. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Is your application redirecting to a secure (https://) url?

If so you'll need to redeclare the :webkit driver for Capybara with the `:ignore_ssl_errors` option set to `true`:

```
Capybara.register_driver :webkit do |app|
  Capybara::Driver::Webkit.new(app, :ignore_ssl_errors => true)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say that we just had the same error on our Ubuntu CI server.  It's an LTS build and so was running an older libqt (v4.6.2) - upgrading (using the tarball) to 4.7.4 fixed the problem.  Probably won't help your situation, but something worth checking.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, I had the problem above and this made me realise that between installing capybara-webkit and then using it, I'd updated QT to 4.8 on my machine and I needed to rebuild the gem :) Saved me hours of frustration

Comment: Thanks for the comment (I recognize you from #rubyonrails :) - I was hoping someone would see it and it'd be just that little hint they needed.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu were you running, @smathy?

Comment: We were running 10.04 LTS on that server.